# value of a factor variable is different than level

Tags: r

I have a factor variable in a dataframe as follows

```
str(x)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ PK                : chr  "1-108" "1-10M" "1-10F" "1-10Q" ...
 $ var1      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ var2: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

when I subset x on var1, value of factor variable shows 2 in str command

```
y <- x[x$var1== 1,]
str(y)
'data.frame':   300 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ PK  : chr  "1-12U" "1-13895" "1-13R" "1-149" ...
 $ var1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ var2: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 ...
```

but actual value of var1 is 1

```
y$var1
   [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, factors are actually expressed internally as natural numbers starting from 1 and mapped sequentially to factor levels. With 'str(y)' you get internal expression, and by 'print(y)' or simply 'y' in interactive environment you get mapped value.

Let me show you:

```
> t = c("0", "0", "1", "1")
> t
[1] "0" "0" "1" "1"
> t2 = as.factor(t)
> t2
[1] 0 0 1 1
Levels: 0 1
> str(t2)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2
> t2[t2 == 0]
[1] 0 0
Levels: 0 1
> str(t2[t2 == 0])
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you filter your data, levels of factor `var1` is not change.

```
x <- factor(1, levels = c(0, 1))
str(x)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2
```